# GORM Error on insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have the following set of GORM models, with 2 orders of one-to-many relations:

```golang
type Order struct {
    ID       string  `gorm:"column:id"`
    ClientID string  `gorm:"primaryKey;column:client_id"`
    Name     string  `gorm:"column:name"`
    Albums   []Album `gorm:"foreignKey:RequestClientID"`
}

type Album struct {
    AlbumID         string    `gorm:"primaryKey;column:album_id"`
    RequestClientID string    `gorm:"foreignKey:ClientID;column:request_client_id"`
    Pictures        []Picture `gorm:"foreignKey:AlbumID"`
}

type Picture struct {
    PictureID   string `gorm:"primaryKey;column:picture_id"`
    AlbumID     string `gorm:"foreignKey:AlbumID;column:album_id"`
    Description string `gorm:"column:description"`
}
```

When I attempt to insert data as follows, I get the error `pq: insert or update on table "albums" violates foreign key constraint "fk_orders_albums"`.

```golang
test := Order{
    ID:       "abc",
    ClientID: "client1",
    Name:     "Roy",
    Albums: []Album{
        {
            AlbumID: "al_1",
            Pictures: []Picture{
                {
                    PictureID:   "pic_1",
                    Description: "test pic",
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

gormDB.Save(&test)
```

I followed the solution on this similar question, but can't seem to get it to work: [Golang: Gorm Error on insert or update on table violates foreign key contraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71129151/golang-gorm-error-on-insert-or-update-on-table-violates-foreign-key-contraint)

Comment: I think the problem is because PK type is string. If you change it to int, is this error happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across the solution I was looking for while looking into the great answer @giyuu provided. Since I had not saved the item before, I needed to use GORM's `Create` method:

```golang
err = gormDB.Create(&test).Error
```

Then, when I want to perform an update on any of these values, I use the `Save` method, with `FullSaveAssociations` enabled:

```golang
err = gormDB.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Save(&test).Error
```

Answer (score 1):

**Based on your entity model,** Your schema would be like this:

- Orders table is parent table, didn't depend to any table
- Albums table has foreign key request_client_id which refer to orders table column client_id
- Picture table has foreign key album_id which is refer to albums table column album_id

**Based on my exploration** in gorm documentation [here](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html), object in struct will be examine as first association. so, your struct will execute insert to `albums` first which it violate foreign key schema (expect: insert to orders table should be executed before albums).

But if you want to force using your schema, you can use gorm Association feature.
**Here is the idea of using Association:**

*Expected Query in high level:*

- Insert to orders table
- Insert to albums table
- Insert to pictures table

*Association Ideas:*

- Let Albums field value in Orders struct empty
- Append Association Albums to Orders model
- Since there have another association in Albums, use configuration FullSaveAssociation

Here is the following code:

```
picture := []Picture{
    {
        PictureID:   "pic_1",
        Description: "test pic",
    },
}
albums := []Album{
    {
        ID:              "al_1",
        Pictures:        picture,
        RequestClientID: "",
    },
}
orders := Order{
    ID:       "abc",
    ClientID: "client1",
    Name:     "Roy",
}
if err := gormDB.Save(orders).Error; err != nil {
    return
}
if err := gormDB.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Model(&orders).Association("Albums").Append(albums); err != nil {
    return
}
```

Full code could be found [here](https://github.com/asepnur/stackoverflow/blob/master/violate-fk/main.go):

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Ended up just using the `Create` method to perform my save, and then I used the &gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true} option that you brought to my attention to perform the update.